# Prevent two classes from inheriting from a base class with same template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, boost, assert

I have a class that is suppose to be a base class:

```
template<int ID>
class BaseClass { ... };
```

How can I make a compile-time error appear if two classes try to inherit form this base class using the same value of ID. That is - this code is suppose to work:

```
class A : BaseClass<1> { ... }
class B : BaseClass<2> { ... }
```

But this code is suppose to cause an error:

```
class A : BaseClass<1> { ... }
class B : BaseClass<1> { ... }
```

How can one achieve this?
Does BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT help?

Comment: You mean `BaseClass` instead of `ID` in the second and third snippet, I assume?

Comment: @Bartłomiej: I think you wanted to write `class A : BaseClass<1> { ... }` instead of `class A : ID<1> { ... }`.

Comment: You are right - it was suppose to be `BaseClass`. My mistake.

Comment: Just a question, when do we benifit from this? I mean why do you want to do that?

Comment: I think it can even be proven that it's impossible. First of all you cannot do it even with a non-template class. And here's why. If it can be done once, you can just copy all the same files, just change the names of the derived classes and you'll end up with two implementations. Bare in mind that modularity in C/C++ is achieved though direct text-based inclusion.

Comment: We would benefit from this in a scenario described in this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850213/dynamically-register-constructor-methods-in-an-abstractfactory-at-compile-time-us) to make sure no two messages have the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is impossible.

If it were possible, then we can make compiler to generate error for the following code as well, which is conceptually equivalent to your code.

```
struct Base {};
struct OtherBase {};

struct A : Base {}; //Base is used here!
struct B : Base {}; // error - used base class. please use some other base!
struct C : OtherBase {}; // ok - unused based!
```

Comment: Perhaps it's possible using the macro... Just supposing, actually I don't know the way.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing, but in case you want to generate unique type ids, you may want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922442/unique-class-type-id-that-is-safe-and-holds-across-library-boundaries) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458028/is-there-a-good-pattern-for-creating-a-unique-id-based-on-a-type) question.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any possible solution at compile-time, using C++.

I can think of a possible solution at launch-time (library initialization), but it would be limited.

```
class A: public Base<A,1> {};
```

We have `Base` register the correspondence between the id `1` and the class `typeid(A)` during the library initialization. If an id exists and the classes disagree, then stop the launch.

There is one caveat however:

```
class A: public Base<A,1> {};

class C: public A {};
class D: public A {};
```

Nothing prevents classes deriving from `A` to clash.

I can suggest static analysis: pick up a C++ parser and program a pre-commit hook that will check the modified files and see if they introduce a clash.