# Is possible to use template argument as string?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to use passed template parameter as string. Is it possible?

T is class, what do i need to change to get that code work?

```
void registerClass(const std::string &name, Handler *handler);

template<class T>
void registerClass() {
   registerClass( "get T as string", new DefaultHandler<T>());
}
```

Comment: `register` is a C++ keyword, you can't use it as an identifier name.

Comment: yep mistake, sorry. I've edited it, it's not the real code :)

Comment: Do you really need the type as a string, or just a different string for each type to use as some kind of dictionary key?

Comment: I need it as string. Because i'll access it with that class name.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691697/). Read the answer, it's a good pattern. And if you want demangle the names use `abi::__cxa_demangle()` _(gcc)_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest you can get to get a type as a string is with `typeid( T )->name()`. However, there is no standarization for type names, so you can't trust in getting a valid name from it. A standard compliant implementation may very well return empty strings for all type names.

Comment: `typeid` is an operator, not a function, so it doesn't live in the `std::` namespace. And it returns a pointer so you need to use `->` instead of `.`.

Comment: Yes, there's no standartization, it generates names with numbers. So, i'm looking for any other way if possible without declaration of static method inside of each class that i use there.

Comment: @MiroK: If you really need the class names, then you are out of luck. The best you could do is provide a function `get_type_name` and overload it for each of the types you want to support to return the type name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `typeid(T)` to obtain a `std::type_info` structure to describe the type. This structure, in turn, has a `name()` member that should give you the name.

```
template<class T>
void fooClass() {
   foo( "get " + std::string( typeid(T).name() ) +" as string", new DefaultHandler<T>());
}
```

Comment: You will need a function to clean up the name.  For example, GCC prefixes an arbitrary number.

Comment: On GCC you can put the `typeid` through `abi::__cxa_demangle()` to get a relatively readable type name, but that's not portable.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be a template parameter? Maybe the C processor can help:

```
void registerClass(const std::string &name, Handler *handler);

#define REGISTER_CLASS(t) (registerClass( #t, new DefaultHandler<t>()))

void RegisterMyClasses() {  
  REGISTER_CLASS(int);
  REGISTER_CLASS(Foo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) like C# or Java does.  This is not a mistake.  Reflection has been considered more than once, and intentionally left out of the language.

**HOWEVER**, you **can** get something close to your design.  You will have to do a lot of work yourself.  You will have to, essentially, implement reflection in a language that intentionally doesn't provide it.

Your current design is close.  If I were to implement reflection the way you appear to be going I would do:

```
class Reflection_registry {
    std::map<std::string, Handler*> registry_;

public:
    void registerClass(const std::string& name, Handler* handler) {
        registry_[name] = handler;
    }

    Handler* getHandlerForClass(std::string& name) {
        std::map<std::string, Handler*>::iterator itor = registry_.find(name);
        return itor == registry_.end() ? NULL : itor->second;
    }
}
```

The thing is that **you** will be responsible for coming up with the relevant names, **by hand**, and keeping them up to date.  As others have suggested, you can use `typeid` and [`std::type_info`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/)s to generate the names -- that's pretty much the kind of thing `std::type_info` was designed for.