# Alternative id generators for types

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, c++17

In [a project of mine](https://github.com/skypjack/entt), I have an [ID generator](https://github.com/skypjack/entt/blob/master/src/entt/core/family.hpp) for types that looks similar to this:

```
class Family {
    static std::size_t identifier;

    template<typename...>
    static std::size_t family() {
        static const std::size_t value = identifier++;
        return value;
    }

public:
    template<typename... Type>
    inline static std::size_t type() {
        return family<std::decay_t<Type>...>();
    }
};

std::size_t Family::identifier{};
```

Usage:

```
const auto id = Family::type<FooBar>();
```

It works just fine for my purposes, but it has some limitations. The most annoying one (purpose of the question) is that it fails when used by an executable that links to shared libraries if all of them try to create identifiers. The result is usually that the n-th identifier is assigned to different types across boundaries because each shared library maintains their own separate `Family::identifier`.

Some *shared library guys* pointed out that a more reliable solution would be appreciated, but failed to suggest one that didn't ruin the performance (almost all of them introduce containers, find functionalities and memory allocation).

Is there any alternative approach that works around the aforementioned limitations without losing the performance of the current design?

I searched through SO and found some interesting answers. Many of which were several years old. I'd like to explore solutions up to the latest revision of the standard instead, as long as the interface of the existing class remains intact.
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7692147/476681) is the most interesting one. It uses addresses of static members to achieve the same, but it doesn't fit with the idea of sequentially generated identifiers

**Note**: using RTTI isn't an option unfortunately.

**Note** : ids must be generated sequentially and starting from 0 as in the solution presented above.

Comment: That's a lot of C++ version tags. It'd be best to focus on the version you're actually using as all the previous ones are then implied.

Comment: @tadman Actually a solution that works for at least one of the tags would be fine for me. That's why I put in all of them. If you find they aren't necessary, feel free to edit the list. I'm not that sure what other tags can be right for this kind of question. Help is appreciated.

Comment: @Justin Good point. No, RTTI isn't an option. I'm editing the question to add this note. Thanks.

Comment: I would use the address of static class members as unique type identifiers. As long as ODR rules the day, an empty `class Identifier{};`, a static class member `Identifier id;` in all my classes, and the address of the class member serves as my identifier. To be pedantically correct, I would always use `std::less<Identifier *>;` to compare my pseudo-ids, since, post C++11, `std::less` is guaranteed to implement strict weak ordering of unrelated pointers.

Comment: Not part of your question, but has your solution to be thread-safe?

Comment: Use the tags more carefully than that. If you can do C++17, that's great, the C++14 and C++11 tags are redundant. When people go looking for questions to answer they're not likely to look for C++11 specific ones, they'll look for C++. Use the other tags to try and classify your problem instead. Is Boost an option, for example?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Unfortunately, this way ids are generated as a sequence as it happens now. It's a requirement. Updated question.

Comment: @StephanLechner Not necessarily, but it would be appreciated.

Comment: @tadman Cleaned up tags and no, boost isn't an option.

Comment: Which platforms are you targeting? On Linux, this can be easily solved. On windows, it may be harder.

Comment: @geza Both, actually. :-)

Comment: You can solve this problem by using a non-class-static variable, but a simple global variable. On linux, this solution works out of the box (put this variable into the main executable, and use extern variables in shared objects). On windows, I'd use a separate small dll, which contains this global variable, and exports it. And all dll's and main exe imports this dll.

Comment: But you could still have problems with the static variables defined in the `family()` functions. Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for that.

Comment: can you add links to some interesting answers in your question?

Comment: @BЈовић Do you mean external links to answers from the web? I didn't get you, sorry.

Comment: @skypjack "I searched through SO and found some interesting answers. " at the end of the question. Can you add links to some?

Comment: @BЈовић Probably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922442/unique-class-type-id-that-is-safe-and-holds-across-library-boundaries) is the most interesting one. It uses addresses of static members to achieve the same, but it doesn't fit with the idea of _sequentially generated identifiers_.

Comment: I'd take a look how `std::any` works w/o RTTI. It should have similar problems and perhaps solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem occurs because you have this line in your header file:

```
std::size_t Family::identifier{};
```

It therefore ends up in each translation unit.  Instead, you need to move the storage for this to a .cpp source file which is compiled only once, perhaps into a shared library of its own.  Then there will be just one instance of `identifier` in a program, and it will work as you intend.

You could also move `identifier` from being a class `static` variable to a global `extern` one in the header file (and as above, define it in a single .cpp file).

If you have C++17 or later, you can also try:

```
inline std::size_t Family::identifier{};
```

While the language does not guarantee (or even mention) what happens when you use this new feature across shared libraries boundaries, it does work on my machine.

Comment: This might not work because the same type, when compiled into a different shared library, will have its own definition of `type` and `family` resulting in different values for `id` in different shared library files.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: I tried it and it works fine for me.

Comment: Put the code in a separate .DLL/.SO file.  Since the DLL and EXE have different copies of `type` and `family`, you'll get different values for `Family::type<FooBar>();` in the EXE and the DLL.

Comment: It's a header-only library, I cannot put something in a .cpp file actually. I'm sorry.

Comment: Then this is simply something that's not possible in header only library. C++ does not work this way. Actually, doing this in the header file violates the ODR, and that's the reason why you get duplicate identifiers: undefined behavior.

Comment: @skypjack: You say it's a header-only library.  Can you publish a special header which is to be `#include`d in exactly one .cpp file in the final application?  That is, require your users to put the storage for `identifier` in their executable?  In case that's not possible for some reason, would you be willing to store a file on disk to make this mechanism work?  Or do something platform-specific (i.e. only needs to work on Linux)?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I suspect you didn't look at the actual implementation of the class (link in the question) before to write your comment. That's why you're comment is pointless after all.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm just exploring other solutions, so all what you mentioned is possible.

Comment: Can't you make it an inline variable to avoid the need to put it in the cpp file?

Comment: @EdLambert: How is that different to OP's original code (which doesn't work)?

Comment: @JohnZwinck An inline variable has the property that "It has the same address in every translation unit" ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline ). usually you achieved that by defining the variable in a cpp file, but with the `inline` specifier you can just declare/define your variables in a header file and every translation unit using this inline variable uses exaclty the same object. dont know about this guarantee when mixing different shared librarys (they dont know each other beforehand, so who is responsible for the ONE and ONLY variable definition). you could try it though.

Comment: @phön: Thanks, I did try it and it works on my machine, though I don't see any reason to believe it would work on every platform.  I added a note about `inline` in my answer.

Comment: @skypjack: Please see the new addendum to this answer, thanks to Ed Lambert and phön.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It sounds interesting indeed. What's scaring is the fact that it isn't guaranteed by the standard if I got your comments. It looks risky to rely on such a solution unfortunately.

Comment: Its well defined for different translation units. The question which remains is whether its defined for mixing and using an inline variable in a shared and/or static library and the executeable or not. When watching this talk ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVT1y0xWgww&feature=youtu.be&t=18m9s ), i get the impression that its just well defined and just works. Inline comes into play @ the time marked. But you would probably need to watch a bit more upfront to get the context.

Comment: @phön Yeah, I know how it works for different translation units, but I've never thought it was the same across boundaries. The main problem is that it seems it isn't guaranteed, but it's interesting anyway. I'll get it a chance with different compilers and let's see. Probably this point is worth creating its own question on SO, you know? :-)

Comment: @skypjack: I agree it's worth a new question just for that (please link to it here!).  However, in general the C++ standard doesn't specify what happens in shared objects and the like--that's an implementation feature which is not determined by the language.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yeah, I see, but sometimes it happens that the standard defines things in such a way that actual implementations haven't much freedom. Btw, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374558/are-inline-variables-unique-across-boundaries) it is the other question around. Let's see, it's definitely interesting. I'd prefer to wait an answer for that before to accept this answer, if it's fine for you. This way you can integrate further for future readers. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not require ids to be sequential integers, you can use an address of a static member of a template as an id. The benefit of this approach is that it does not require any run-time initialization (uses [static initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables)):

```
// in a header
class Family {
    template<class...> struct Id { static char const id; };

    template<typename... T>
    static std::size_t family() {
        return reinterpret_cast<std::size_t>(&Id<T...>::id);
    }

public:
    template<typename... Type>
    static std::size_t type() {
        return family<std::decay_t<Type>...>();
    }
};

// in a header
template<class... T>
char const Family::Id<T...>::id = {};

// elsewhere    
int main() {
    auto int_id = Family::type<int>();
    auto int_int_id = Family::type<int, int>();
}
```

---

You can also make that `id` a compile time constant and use it as a template argument:

```
// in a header
struct Family {
    template<class...> struct Id { static char const id; };
};

// in a header
template<class... T>
char const Family::Id<T...>::id = {};

// elsewhere    
template<char const*>
struct X {};

int main() {
    X<&Family::Id<int>::id> x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you don't care about sequential IDs, use the address of the function as identifier.

```
template<typename... T>
uintptr_t getID() {
    return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&getID<T...>);
}
```

and then

```
auto intID = getID<int>();
auto floatID = getID<float>();
...
```